# vector of class scope issue?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
vector<ClassX> xVec;

if (inputFile.peek() == '$')
{
    classX classXInstance;           //<==================== local instantiation
    readFileElements(classXInstance);//<== pass by reference
    if(classXInstance.validate())
    {
       xVec.push_back(classXInstance);///<=============== added here
    }
    /// destructor of the local copy is called here
}
```

I get a core dump, tried to debug, however I get so much junk messages with gdb, all I can see that the vector got corrupted, NOT sure if it because the destructor is called is a reason??

**EDIT:**

my class look like this

```
class ClassX
{
 public:
    ClassX() { numberOfX=0; ppXX = NULL; };
   ~ClassX();
   void validate();
   char **setX(const vector<string>& Xss);
   inline char **getX() {return ppXX;};
 private:
    int numberOfX;
    char **ppXX;
};
```

and it contains a destructor as follow

```
ClassX::~ClassX()
{
    if (ppXX != NULL)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < numberOfXX; i++)
        {
            if (ppXX[i] != NULL)
            {
                delete [] ppXX[i];
                ppXX[i] = NULL;
            }
        }

        // Free array of pointers.
        delete [] ppXX;
        ppXX = NULL;
    }
}
```

the setX allocate all memory necessary

validate give me a printout of the ppXX[i] and return true if number of elements matches the size of string vector

Comment: And you follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) for your `ClassX`?

Comment: Can you post the definition of `ClassX`? A copy of `classXInstance` will be made at the call of `push_back()`. If `ClassX` has any dynamically allocated members the rule of three must be followed. Or, if c++11 support it could be moved instead: `xVec.push_back(std::move(classXInstance));`.

Comment: I'm al-but-guaranteeing `readFileElements()` performs dynamic allocation for member variables of `ClassX` and said-class does NOT conform to the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: This needs more information. Could you post the junk messages, please?

Comment: I didnt have all three!

Comment: @hmjd or rather, `xVec.emplace_back(std::move(classXInstance));`

Comment: @FabioA.Correa, I don't think so as the instance already exists.

Comment: this is good, but I dont have C++11 support yet

Comment: what don't you store a vector of strings? (doesn't preclude you from having to follow the rule of three, but I'd imagine it's a little cleaner?

Comment: I implemented a copy constructor, and the issue were gone :)

Comment: Consider using a vector of strings; let the computer help you with the plumbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A copy of `classXinstance` is stored into `xVec`, with a pointer `ppXX` to a region in memory. Now you have two objects pointing to the same region. A moment later, `classXinstance` is destroyed, so the region is subject to `delete`. The element within xVec is now pointing to invalid memory.

The best option is to use `std::Vector<std::string>` instead of `char **ppXX`; a vector of strings takes care of references and allocation so you don't need to worry about proper construction/copy/destruction.

Comment: yes, I know but I am trying to send ppXX which is the argv to execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]); system call, so it will have to be a double pointer

Comment: @abdul No, you could convert from `string` to `char **` just before calling `exec()`; there is no need to store it internally in this form.

Comment: Convert it to char** as the last step before execv(); this way, and with the vector of strings, the computer will be helping you with memory management. Create a std::vector<char*> arguments, fill it with each string's data(), and finally run execv(path, arguments.data())